# Passing state as initial value to another state is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm setting the initial value of correctAnswer state by extracting the data from another. Its giving me undefined. but same value is console logging correctly.

```
  let refinedAnswer = questions[currentQuestion]?.correct_answer;

  //correct answer for each question
  const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = React.useState(refinedAnswer);

 console.log("CORRECT ANS", correctAnswer); //undefined
 console.log("CORRECT ANS", questions[currentQuestion]?.correct_answer); //value
```

Comment: The issue is that when first rendered the"correctAnswer" is undefined due to the optional chaining.  The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined. You can try checking if refinedAnswer is not undefined in the useEffect hook and then update the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the value in useEffect.
For example:

```
useEffect(() => setCorrectAnswer(refinedAnswer), [refinedAnswer])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the useEffect hook to update the state when "undefined" turns into a value. Then the component is rerendered with the correct value:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    setCorrectAnswer(refinedAnswer);
  }, [refinedAnswer]);

  console.log("CORRECT ANS", correctAnswer);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sanne-qr0cg?file=/src/App.js